# use \cref within enumerate and theorem

Tags: enumerate, cleveref, ref

I want to reference a certain part of a definition, which is separated using the `enumerate` environment.
In a MWE I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    
    \begin{defin}\label{defin_1}$ $
        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item\label{item_1} Part 1
            \item\label{item_2} Part 2
        \end {enumerate}
    \end{defin}
    In \cref{defin_1} I have the items \cref{item_1} and \cref{item_2}.

\end{document}
```

from which I get

[image]

Is there a way to automatically replace `Item (i)` and `Item (ii)` by `Definition 1.1 (i)` and `Definition 1.1 (ii)` respectively?

I can't use the normal `\ref` because all my definitions/theorems/lemmas etc. share one single counter.

Comment: You should be able to use `\ref` for an item in the `enumerate` without interfering with use of `\ref` for numbers of theorems, definitions, etc.. So add to preamble: `\newcommand{\crefthmpart}[2]{\cref{#1}~\ref{#2}}` and then in the body of the document: `In \cref{defin_1} I have the items \crefthmpart{defin_1}{item_1}  and \crefthmpart{defin_1}{item_2}.`

Comment: but this will give me 2 separate hrefs, the first pointing to the definition, the second to the item. However, I want one single one pointing to the item.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the requirement of a single href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a simpler, more direct way, but the following seems to do what you want. (And it should work not just for the specific `definition` environment, but for all theorem-like environments.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definition}

\newcommand{\crefdefpart}[2]{%
  \hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~\ref*{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    
    \begin{defin}\label{defin_1}$ $
        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item\label{item_1} Part 1
            \item\label{item_2} Part 2
        \end {enumerate}
    \end{defin}
    
   In \cref{defin_1} I have the items \crefdefpart{defin_1}{item_1}  and \crefdefpart{defin_1}{item_2}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Referencing part of enumerate in theorem-like environment]

Comment: thx, that works. I only changed the new command to `\hyperref[#1]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~\ref*{#2}}`, so the view starts at the `theorem-like`, not directly at the referenced part of it.

Comment: @Xoriun: However, that change from `\hyperref[#2]` to `\hyperref[#1]` does not create a link to the particular part but rather the the entire theorem. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want, because I usually have some general information at the top before the individual parts which I don't want to scroll up to.

Comment: This solution has a problem: Because the line `\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~\ref*{#2}}` is not terminated by `%`, i.e., the comment character, there's extra -- and presumably unwanted -- whitespace after the output of `\crefdefpart`. The fix? Affix [pun intended] a comment character at the end of the line `\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~\ref*{#2}}`.

Comment: @Mico: Fixed. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

You asked,

> Is there a way to automatically replace "Item (i)" and "Item (ii)" by "Definition 1.1 (i)" and "Definition 1.1 (ii)" respectively?

A solution that preserves the ability of `\cref` to take multiple arguments is to employ the machinery of the `enumitem` package -- specifically, its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros -- to create a bespoke enumerate-like list environment whose `\item`s, upon cross-referencing, think of themselves as "definitions" rather than as "items".

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definition}

\newlist{definenum}{enumerate}{1} % should only occur inside definition env.
\setlist[definenum]{label=(\roman*),ref=\thedefin\,(\roman*)}
\crefname{definenumi}{definition}{definitions}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
    
\begin{defin}\label{defin_1}
\leavevmode % more elegant than '$ $'
   \begin{definenum}
      \item\label{item_1} Part 1 \dots
      \item\label{item_2} Part 2 \dots
   \end{definenum}
\end{defin}
    
\noindent
\cref{defin_1} consists of the \cref{item_1,item_2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to work for all `theorem` environments, besides defining a lot of lists?

Comment: @mixotrov - The short answer to your question must be a simple "yes". A longer, and hopefully more useful, answer will depend critically on how the theorem-like environments are organized: How many of them are there? Do they share a common counter, or does each theorem-like environment come with its own, independent counter? And, of course, which purpose is being pursued by populating the theorem-like environments with enumerated lists? Is there, in fact, a common purpose? If you want to pursue these ideas some more, please post a new query.