# Unwanted spaces when cross-referencing a sub-theorem

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem, cleveref

I have the same problem as the link [use \cref within enumerate and theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588480/use-cref-within-enumerate-and-theorem). However, after applying the provided method in the answer box, I found there are two extra spaces before and after my item referred. Help appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %The secnumdepth value determines up to what level the sectioning titles are numbered
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %the tocdepth value determines to which level the sectioning commands are printed in the ToC
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\Crefdefpart}[2]{
  \nameCref{#1}~\hyperref[#2]{\labelcref*{#1}\ref*{#2}}
  }
\crefname{enumi}{part}{parts}
\crefname{exercise}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{example}{example}{examples}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm3.10}\leavevmode 
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
    \item\label{thm3.10a} If $\overline{E}$ is the closure of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$, then
    \begin{equation*}
        \operatorname{diam} \overline{E} = \operatorname{diam} E
    \end{equation*}
    \item \label{thm3.10b}If $K_{n}$ is a sequence of compact sets in $X$ such that $K_{n} \supset K_{n+1}$ and if 
    \begin{equation*}
        \lim_{n\to \infty} \operatorname{diam}K_{n} = 0
    \end{equation*}
    then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_{n}$ consists of exactly one point.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

From \Crefdefpart{thm3.10}{thm3.10a}, we see two extra spaces before and after the theorem.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is the following construct:

```
\newcommand{\Crefdefpart}[2]{
  \nameCref{#1}~\hyperref[#2]{\labelcref*{#1}\ref*{#2}}
  }
```

TeX changes invisible end-of-line characters to whitespace. Because the construct contains *two* line breaks not terminated by a comment character, you get extra whitespace both before and after the output of the instruction.

The remedy? Insert comment characters, i.e., `%`, at the ends of both lines:

```
\newcommand{\Crefdefpart}[2]{%
  \nameCref{#1}~\hyperref[#2]{\labelcref*{#1}\ref*{#2}}%
  }
```

Comment: +1, but you’re stealing my job! 